# Android Chrome Facebook webview memory leak using Leakcanary

Tags: android, facebook, memory-leaks, chromium, leakcanary

Randomly I'm having this leaks after performing login with `Facebook` `Webview`

[image]
[image]
[image]

I've found this (the only mention to `com.android.org.chromium`):

```
AW_RESOURCE__SRESOURCES(SAMSUNG.equals(MANUFACTURER) && SDK_INT == KITKAT) {
    @Override void add(ExcludedRefs.Builder excluded) {
      // AwResource#setResources() is called with resources that hold a reference to the
      // activity context (instead of the application context) and doesn't clear it.
      // Not sure what's going on there, input welcome.
      excluded.staticField("com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwResource", "sResources");
    }
  },
```

Inside this class [AndroidExcludedRefs.java](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/blob/master/leakcanary-android/src/main/java/com/squareup/leakcanary/AndroidExcludedRefs.java)

> This class is a work in progress. You can help by reporting leak
>   traces that seem to be caused by the Android SDK, here:
>   https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/new

But I'm not using Samsung so I'm still having this leak.
Said that, is this leak a known issue? Can it be ignored?

**UPDATE:** I was using Facebook SDK v3.19, I've updated to 4.3 but the problem remains:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've been in contact with facebook support center and the conclusion we've reached was:

> Your intuition was correct. This seems to be a bug in chrome and not
>   our SDK. It should be fixed in later versions of android since it was
>   fixed in April of this year.
>
> See: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=478719

Answer (score 1):

There were a couple of memory leak fixes in the latest versions of the Facebook SDK. Make sure you download the latest (v4.3 as of now).

Comment: I was using 3.19.0 and I've updated to 3.23.1 but the leaks still continue to appear. Tomorrow I'll update to 4.x.x because the logic changes significantly. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: so I've update to the latest version of Facebook SDK 4.3 and the leaks still happen.

Comment: Still leaking in v4.5